# trying to show hidden divs based on todays date first JS project

Tags: javascript, css

as above, the divs are hidden by default using CSS. I have this script so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeDate(){ // makes the date and defines "today" variable for data-display-before" and "data-display-after" to work. also logs todays date to console for troubleshooting
    var now = new Date();
    var day = now.getDate();
    var month = now.getMonth()+1;
    today = month+"-"+day;
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".date-display-after").getAttribute();
    var y = document.querySelectorAll(".date-display-before").getAttribute();
    console.log("the date today in MM/DD format is "+today); //for troubleshooting

    if (today >= x && today <= y){ //the juicy bit
        document.getElementById(".hidden").style.display = 'block';
    }
}   
    //setInterval("makeDate()", 3000);
</script>
```

I suspect this is not working because I can't compare integers with strings? either that or the problem is syntactical. I'm trying to follow an answer I had on a related post that read "Add two attributes to the divs in question like data-display-after and data-display-before, for example:

```
<div id="valentines" 
    data-display-after="2016-02-14 00:00:00" 
    data-display-before="2016-02-15 00:00:00">...Hide these divs initially (with CSS).
```

On page load, convert the current date (new Date) into the above format.

For each element in document that has the data-display-before attribute (you'll need querySelectorAll), compare attribute values (getAttribute) and

```
if currentDate >= data-display-after && currentDate <= data-display-after, 
then show the element."
```

I'd appreciate some advice on how best to handle the variables. Heres what the HTML looks like:

```
<body onload="makeDate()">
<div class="occasion" id="hidden" date-display-after="02-01" date-display-before="02-15">
<div class="textbox"><h5>Valentines day</h5><p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime nobis non veritatis quaerat eveniet, necessitatibus, assumenda alias in voluptatum eius voluptate beatae doloribus sed rem officiis ullam perspiciatis earum, aliquam.</span>
<span>Incidunt officiis eligendi quisquam debitis! Vitae voluptates cum architecto culpa voluptatum nam excepturi laborum. Omnis quasi aut ea explicabo, porro quisquam reiciendis animi, mollitia, et error earum tempora, ad asperiores.</span>
<span>Commodi necessitatibus et atque odio eos, itaque quaerat, unde animi, provident deserunt quisquam fugit porro fugiat blanditiis quibusdam culpa quo deleniti molestiae numquam dignissimos alias! Inventore libero incidunt, alias possimus!</span></p></div>
<div class="picture"></div>
```

The div should be visible today because the console outputs:

```
the date today in MM/DD format is 2-5
```

Comment: Interesting question.  One problem I see is that you probably mean to use querySelectorAll(".occasion") to get all occasions, and then for each use getAttribute to get the after and before dates -- as is, your x and y variables are empty.

Comment: `document.getElementById(".hidden")` is incorrect. It should be `document.getElementById("hidden")`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jason, I have edited the code above, still no luck.

Comment: Furthermore, you're doing comparisons on string values as opposed to numeric values... You should be using a singular value (like milliseconds since Epoch) as suggested by @sideroxylon

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, the time calculation is not seen by the user, so why do you need to convert everything to a MM/DD format? It would be easier to convert your start and end dates to times and compare them to now

```js
//Get current time
var d = new Date();
//get year
var y = d.getFullYear();
//Convert to milliseconds
var n = d.getTime();

//Convert dates to date objects
var x = y + '-01-14T00:00:00';
var s = new Date(x);
var y = y + '-02-15T00:00:00';
var e = new Date(y);

//Convert to milliseconds
var start = s.getTime();
var end = e.getTime();

//compare
if (n >= start && n <= end) {
  console.log('show hidden div');
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for getting back. I'm converting to MM/DD because I want to make sure the code is correct in 2017 and 2018 etc... Do you think that this is possible?

Comment: getTime() gives you an absolute number for any date/time, equal to the milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970.  It's easier just to compare these than to convert to MM/DD.

Comment: The problem with this is I have 6 divs I want to show and each of them at their own certain times of the year, I also need this code to work next year and the year after.

Comment: OK - I've updated the answer to show how you can add the year dynamically from the `new Date()` function.